# jQuery serialize hidden (display:none) form elemens does not work. Workaround?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I have the following problem:

I have a form I need to serialize but I am using javascript to change the look of the select fields. This means, the real select fields are hidden using display:none.
My Problem is now, that jQuery does recognize the hidden selects, but only serializes the first value and not the selected one.

`<select name="publish">

<option value="1">yes</option>

<option value="2" selected="selected">no</option>

</select>`

> jQuery.serialzie: publish=1

so it gives me the first and not the correct value.

Any ideas for a workaround?

**Solutions**
Okay, as mentioned by RobW, the best solution is probably to just let the JavaScript select the option you want by setting the `selectElement.selectedIndex = 5`

My solution however is a little different, because I do not want to change the plugin used to change the appearance of my selects, due to maintenance problems (as in, needing to change the script every time they release a new version). 
I did just use a custom function for serialization.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.serializer = function() {
    var toReturn    = [];
    var elements         = $(this).find(':input').get();
    $.each(elements, function() {
        if (this.name && !this.disabled && (this.checked || /select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName) || /text|hidden|password/i.test(this.type))) 
        {
            var val = $(this).val();
            // if is select, check selected
            if(this.nodeName == "SELECT")
            {
                val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();    
            }
            toReturn.push( encodeURIComponent(this.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( val ) );
        }
    });
    return toReturn.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the issue is caused by hidden elements, temporary show them before serializing:

```
var $form = $('#myForm');
var hidden = $form.find(':hidden'); // Select all hidden elements
hidden.show();                      // Show them
var string = $form.serialize();     // Serialize form
hidden.hide();                      // Hide them again
```

Edit: It seems that you're trying to select an option by setting the `selected=selected` attribute. You should use `selectedIndex` to change the selected option:

```
var select = $("#myselect")[0]; //DOM element
select.selectedIndex = 5;       //Example, select 6th option
```

Comment: Yeah, good idea, I tried it, but the problem seems to be something else. When I use normal dropdowns it works. I figured it might be, that serialize does not like selected="selected". Is that possible? Because the script I use sets the selected dropdown field to selected, but when you normally select an option of a select it does not get set to selected. Could that be the problem? And how do I stop it?

Comment: How are you selecting an option? The best method to select: `selectElement.selectedIndex = 5` (where selectElement is the DOM element, and 5 is the index of the option).

Comment: I was selecting by setting it to selected="selected" which apparently does not work. But I guess yours works. If you could post it as an answer I can check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native js

Example

```
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var string = new URLSearchParams(data).toString();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).