# JQuery hidden field value null when form is serialized and posted

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, serialization

I have the following html script:

```
<form id="myForm">
...
<input hidden name="myInput" id="myInput">
...
</form>
```

And somewhere I set a value for the hidden input:

```
$('#myInput').val('a value here');
```

then, I serialize the form and post it in an url:

```
$.post("my_url_here", $("#myForm").serialize())
```

Where I handle this post, I try to access my hidden input value with:

```
$_POST['myInput']
```

but it shows null (empty actually), when I expect it to have the value that I set before. If I explicitly set the value like this:

```
<input hidden name="myInput" id="myInput" value="explicit_value">
```

it works fine. Any idea what's going on?

UPDATE (the whole code, the order is the same as in my real code):

```
<script>

    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
           eventHandler(){
             ...
             $('#myInput').val('a value here');
             myPostFunction();
          }
    });

</script>
<form id="myForm">
    ...
    <input hidden name="myInput" id="myInput">
    ...
</form>
<script>

    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
           window.myPostFunction= function () {
             alert($("#myForm").serialize());//It shows myField=&otherField=value
             alert($("#myInput").val());// This shows the correct value.
             $.post("my_url_here", $("#myForm").serialize());
          }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: That should work... Try doing `console.log($("#myForm").serialize())` before sending it. Perhaps your `$('#myInput').val('a value here')` is being executed after the POST to the php.

Comment: Well, I set some values for visible fields and it works fine. I'm going to try but it should be something else.

Comment: @MatiTucci I did it and yes, the value of that field is empty. I added some delay to the post function but still the same. But the odd thing is that when I alert the $('#myInput').val() just before the post, it is ok.

Comment: When you console `$("#myForm").serialize()` are you seeing the property without the value? Or not seeing that input name at all? Because if you are not seeing it is because you don't have it inside your `<form>`

Comment: What I can think of is, probably you put your $.POST script on top of the form element, so basically the ajax gets executed first before the form element gets loaded. But better if you provide us your full source code, we can help you more as we will know where the problem is :)

Comment: @MatiTucci I see the input name but the value is empty. When I alert it it is OK. So, it doesn't work when I serialize the form.

Comment: Post the whole code. You probably have a timing problem.

Comment: OK guys, there is my code. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thank you all for your help but finally I found the solution. It was the name of the field that wasn't OK. I just changed the name of the field and it is fine now. It should have been a conflict with the name but I did't realize it since the script executed fine. After trying all, I thought to change the name... Again, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but try to compare with mine, and see the result :)
You are using PHP right?
Try to create a new php file, named sendAjax.php and type this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281545/jquery-hidden-field-value-null-when-form-is-serialized-and-posted</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="myInput" id="myInput"/>
        </form>
        <script>
            (function(){
                $('#myInput').val('a value here');
                $.post("receiveAjax.php", $("#myForm").serialize(), 
                    function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And create another new php file, named receiveAjax.php, put it into the same folder as sendAjax.php and type this :

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST;
    var_dump($data);
?>
```

Comment: Please, see my comment above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"hidden" should be the value of the "type" attribute, I don't know if it's related but try to replace :

```
<input hidden name="myInput" id="myInput">
```

By :

```
<input type="hidden" name="myInput" id="myInput">
```

Comment: I found this post, try to show() the hidden elements just before serializing then hide() them : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023771/jquery-serialize-hidden-displaynone-form-elemens-does-not-work-workaround
On this one it's display related but you can try anyway (it could be a jquery issue even if hidden type inputs don't have any visual..)

Comment: Also, because you said that if you explicitly specify a value in html it works, you can try to set the value like this : 
  `document.getElementById('myInput').value = 'myvalue';`
or even like this :
  `document.getElementById('myInput').setAttribute('value', 'myvalue');`
and then do your serialize.